# Library interpositioning

Tags: c, dlsym, library-interposition

I have been trying to intercept calls to malloc and free, following our textbook (CSAPP book).
I have followed their exact code, and nearly the same code that I found online and I keep getting a segmentation fault. I heard our professor saying something about printf that mallocs and frees memory so I think that this happens because I am intercepting a malloc and since I am using a printf function inside the intercepting function, it will call itself recursively.
However I can't seem to find a solution to solving this problem? Our professor demonstrated that intercepting worked ( he didn't show us the code) and prints our information every time a malloc occurs, so I do know that it's possible.
Can anyone suggest a working method??

Here is the code that I used and get nothing:
mymalloc.c

```
#ifdef RUNTIME
// Run-time interposition of malloc and free based on // dynamic linker's (ld-linux.so) LD_PRELOAD mechanism #define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> #include <dlfcn.h>
void *malloc(size_t size) {
static void *(*mallocp)(size_t size) = NULL; char *error;
void *ptr;
// get address of libc malloc
if (!mallocp) {
mallocp = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc"); if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
            fputs(error, stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
}
ptr = mallocp(size);
printf("malloc(%d) = %p\n", (int)size, ptr); return ptr;
}
#endif
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   printf("main\n");
   int* a = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
   a[0] = 1;
   printf("end\n");
}
```

The result i'm getting:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ gcc -DRUNTIME -shared -fPIC mymalloc.c -o mymalloc.so
$ LD_PRELOAD=./mymalloc.so ./test
Segmentation Fault
```

This is the code that I tried and got segmentation fault (from https://gist.github.com/iamben/4124829):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
        static void* (*rmalloc)(size_t) = NULL;
        void* p = NULL;

        // resolve next malloc
        if(!rmalloc) rmalloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

        // do actual malloc
        p = rmalloc(size);

        // show statistic
        fprintf(stderr, "[MEM | malloc] Allocated: %lu bytes\n", size);

        return p;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STR_LEN 128

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
        char *c;
        char *str1 = "Hello ";
        char *str2 = "World";

        //allocate an empty string
        c = malloc(STR_LEN * sizeof(char));
        c[0] = 0x0;

        //and concatenate str{1,2}
        strcat(c, str1);
        strcat(c, str2);

        printf("New str: %s\n", c);


        return 0;
}
```

The makefile from the git repo didn't work so I manually compiled the files and got:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC libint.c -o libint.so
$ gcc -o str str.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libint.so ./str
Segmentation fault
```

I have been doing this for hours and I still get the same incorrect result, despite the fact that I copied textbook code. I would really appreciate any help!!

Comment: Try `fprintf(stderr, ...)` to avoid recursion. `stderr` is unbuffered.

Comment: @chqrlie I have already tried that and still get the same error... Might there be an issue with the gcc compiling statement??

Comment: You could also try `sprintf(buf, ...)` to a a local array and `write(2, buf, strlen(buf))`

Comment: Does it work if you just write a constant string with `write()` from your `malloc`?

Comment: If you just want to trace malloc / free, you can use environment variables. see `man malloc`

Comment: @chqrlie: Buffering is not the issue, and `sprintf` with `write` will not work either. The issue is `printf` allocates some space to do its formatting work, and so does `sprintf`. That formatting is done preparing the string to be written to the stream, so it occurs before any buffering occurs.

Comment: @chqrlie I did try using write which kind of worked! I'm getting prints of the "buf" excessively until I get Segmentation Fault, which confirms that it was the recursion that was the problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to turn off the `printf` when your return is called recursively:

```
static char ACallIsInProgress = 0;
if (!ACallIsInProgress)
{
    ACallIsInProgress = 1;
    printf("malloc(%d) = %p\n", (int)size, ptr);
    ACallIsInProgress = 0;
}
return ptr;
```

With this, if `printf` calls `malloc`, your routine will merely call the actual malloc (via `mallocp`) and return without causing another `printf`. You will miss printing information about a call to `malloc` that the `printf` does, but that is generally tolerable when interposing is being used to study the general program, not the C library.

If you need to support multithreading, some additional work might be needed.

The `printf` implementation might allocate a buffer only once, the first time it is used. In that case, you can initialize a flag that turns off the `printf` similar to the above, call `printf` once in the `main` routine (maybe be sure it includes a nice formatting task that causes `printf` to allocate a buffer, not a plain string), and then set the flag to turn on the `printf` call and leave it set for the rest of the program.

Another option is for your `malloc` routine not to use `printf` at all but to cache data in a buffer to be written later by some other routine or to write raw data to a file using `write`, with that data interpreted and formatted by a separate program later. Or the raw data could be written by a pipe to a program that formats and prints it and that is not using your interposed `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wonder however, how the static char works. If the char is 0, it will enter the if condition and return the ptr. Then how will the following statement (where 0 is assigned to the char) execute? What is its purpose??

Comment: Whilst debugging, I found out that it's not actually the printf function that was the problem, but actually the dlsym function (I tried a write() function (writing a string) before and after the dlsym, and the infinite loop of printing the string). How is that possible?? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It is a shame `printf` allocates memory with `malloc` to perform such simple formatting!

Comment: @juimdpp: FYI, I edited the answer to change the code—I did not notice at first the `return` was on the same line as the `printf`. I have moved it outside the `if` statement.

Comment: @juimdpp: The `static char ACallIsInProgress` serves to record whether the `malloc` routine is currently executing and calling `printf`. Declaring it with `static` creates a single `char` object that is used for all calls to the routine, rather than the default of each call having its own separate copy. After we set it to 1 and call `printf`, if `printf` then calls `malloc`, the routine will find `ACallIsInProgress` is not zero and will skip its call to `printf` and will return. Then the first call to `printf` will return, and `malloc` will reset `ACallIsInProgress` to 0 and return.

Comment: @juimdpp: If `dlsym` is calling `malloc`, you may need to move the initialization of `mallocp` out of your `malloc` routine.

Comment: Also make this variable thread-local. (Keyword `__thread` with some compilers.)